# Getting last insert id in Excel ADODB connection to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, excel, adodb

I have the following code to insert items into a MySQL database from an Excel form.

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
ConnectDB
With wsWorkBook
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO work_order (job_status, job_description, system_id) VALUES ....;"
    rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    ' word_order.id
End With
```

How can I get the last insert id of that line, which is in the work_order.id column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the LAST_INSERT_ID() - operator in a following SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: After your code example, just call another SQL-Statement, only this time not an INSERT-Command, but a Select-Statement...

strSQL = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"

...then do whatever you do to execute that query and retrieve that value.